# Asus G751 with nVidia - Can't get any ENBs to work

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I don't get this, I just bought an Asus G751 today with a GTX980m in it. And I've tried ENB addons for both Skyrim and Minecraft now. And none of them seems to be working. I don't get any error message or anything. It just doesn't.. do anything. Atleast as far as I can tell.

For Skyrim I've downloaded Nexus Mod manager and and a couple of ENBs, such as:

- Natural Lighting and Atmospherics for ENB PhotoReal ENB - Performance
- Photoreal ENB V1_2MORE REALISTIC COLOURS_ENBLENS OFF
- enbseries_skyrim_v0264

Although for Minecraft, I downloaded the newest version, 8.1 and tried an Alpha ENB. But since that doesn't seem to do anything either, I thought maybe these two cases are related.

I'm running Windows 8.1 with latest Nvidia drivers 344.75. And I read that Nvidia Geforce Experience might be a nuisance, so I've tried uninstalling it. But no change.

Is it something with Nvidia and ENBs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ENB didn't work on my computer neither for some reason, but most others can. It may be not working on certain cards.

You cannot run an ENB on Minecraft, because it's based on OpenGL, and ENB requires DirectX.

Nvidia graphic cards does support most ENBs.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it by installing the ENBs manually. And not using Nexus mod manager. Haven't tested any Minecraft ENBs yet though.